# Visual C# MessageBox float

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a program with GUI that will design a heat exchanger. I am having some problems with MessageBox.Show, as it won't display the answer to some calculations. Any tips?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        float mc = float.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        mc = mc * (1000 / 3600);
        MessageBox.Show("mc=" + mc);
    }
}
```

PS: I am quite a newbie programmer, so don't be too harsh :D.

Comment: What's an example of not displaying the answer to some calculations?

Comment: `it won't display the answer to some calculations`, what does it display then? Any error?

Comment: it displays 0, no matter what input

Comment: Are you sure you're inputting the value to the correct textbox? Can you post your designer.cs please?

Comment: `(1000F / 3600F)` else you will always multiply by 0 (integer division).

Comment: @AlexK. Thank you! That worked! I tried adding "F" to mc, but it gave an error. That solved it. Thanks!